# Send Slack notification from Jenkins into private channel of other users

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops, slack

**What i did:**

I managed to send Notifications with Status of every Build to **my** private Slack Channel. So i configured my Jenkins as well as my Slack app.

**What i want to do:**

Sending messages to **other users private** Channels.

**What i have tried:**

I added channels to my Jenkinsfile and checked them in the Slack App of Jenkins and it wasn't successful. I think i have to create sth like a Bot, which is in the specific Channel i want to send a message to. Very sure that Jenkins can't see the channel because its a private channel of another person(obviously) and is not able to find it. Couldn't find a solution for this Problem.

Thanks a lot for your help, i think i wasted way to much time trying to find an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup our build pipeline to send Slack notifications to commit authors.  The biggest challenge is mapping to the Slack username. I had every developer on the team change their git user.name to match their Slack Display name. This is the most straight-forward way I know to make this work.

`git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"` where "Mona Lisa" is the Slack display name of the user.
In the Jenkins pipeline, I used `env.GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR` to get this value back.

Note, that the environment variable provides the commit author at the HEAD of whatever was checked out. For pull requests in a multi-branch pipeline, if the PR is *not* a fast forward, the commit is what the merge would produce, resulting in an author of 'Jenkins'. So, in that case, you would need the author from HEAD~1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is think you got me wrong.

I want to send a Message with the Build status to a private channel of a Person that's not me but Jenkins can't reach it. It works perfectly with channels which are public or mine private channel.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am describing.  The Jenkins build pipeline is sending a build status message to the user's private channel. In my case, the user is the commit author. If there is another way to describe a Slack user's private channel other than Display Name, I am not aware. It was something I looked for when setting up our pipeline and only through experimentation did I find that the @DisplayName worked.

Comment: FYI, there's a Slack API endpoint that will return email addresses for you. You can parse the results and have a mapping between email and Slack ID. We then use commit email address to map into Slack ID.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience sending Slack messages to a private channel requires OAuth. I have only succeeded sending to private channels via `slackSend()` when Jenkins is added to Slack as a bot and invited to the channel.

Here's an example pipeline that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy


pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label "master"
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Send Notification') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def color = "${params.MESSAGE_STATUS}" == "GOOD"? "good" : "warning"
                    slackSend(color: "${color}", message: "${params.MESSAGE}", channel: "${params.CHANNEL}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'MESSAGE', defaultValue: 'Hello')
        string(name: 'CHANNEL', defaultValue: '#test_private')
        choice(name: 'MESSAGE_STATUS', choices: ['GOOD', 'WARNING'], description: '')
    }
}
```

Sending via bots etc. hasn't been successful as Slack reports the channel as non-existant.